# angular-fullstack permission denied rename jquery

Tags: yeoman, package-managers, angular-fullstack

I run `sudo yo angular-fullstack squad` and I get following error message on Mac.

[image]

You can see my Bower and Node version in the screenshot. Do you have an idea how I can solve this?

Best regards,
Marcel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `sudo bower install --allow-root` manually did the trick.